# How to add retry on UpdateRecord method from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am using updateRecord from 'lightning/uiRecordApi' to update contact object from LWC. I am getting locking row errors sometimes when multiple updates are made to contact. So I am thinking to add retry on updateRecord when error occurs. I was able to add retry for wire method as shown below.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: OPP_FIELDS, timeout: 5000, retry: { maxAttempts: 3 }  })
```

I counldn't find how to add retry to this UpdateRecord.
Here is some parts of my code to give better idea.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';

updateContact(recordInput, disclosureField){
        console.log('UPDATING RECORD!');
        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Disclosure updated!',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
                
                // Display fresh data in the form
                return refreshApex(this.contact);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error updating disclosure for this client.',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
                
            });
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add retry functionality for the **updateRecord** method, you can implement a custom retry mechanism within your **updateContact** method.

```
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";

...

const MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 3;
const RETRY_DELAY_MS = 1000;

...

updateContact(recordInput, disclosureField, retryAttempt = 0) {
    console.log('UPDATING RECORD!');
    updateRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Disclosure updated!',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            
            // Display fresh data in the form
            return refreshApex(this.contact);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (retryAttempt < MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.updateContact(recordInput, disclosureField, retryAttempt + 1);
                }, RETRY_DELAY_MS);
            } else {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error updating disclosure for this client.',
                        message: error.body ? error.body.message : 'Unknown error',
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            }
        });
}

...
```